# ssh tunnel through two-factor auth

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, two-factor

I need to connect to server using SSH, and the server has two-factor authentication enabled and secretkey disabled. Now, I can connect "manually" form the shell with the help of Google authenticator app.

Problem is that many of the tools that I regularly use don't support 2FA (i.e. they never ask me for the additional key but simply fail to connect).

Can I somehow make a connection to the server and then "forward" it to a port locally?

P.S.
I'm connecting from a mac, and I don't have root access on the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a persistent connection using the initial login, and then instruct ssh to reuse it for all subsequent connections. It's called "ControlMaster" -- there's multiple resources online on how to set it up, e.g. see [this PuppetLabs article](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections).

Comment: This really works! :)  And for SFTP too.